# How to load ajax data fade in and scroll to newest items w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

Have this almost working, it loads the newest posts 3 at a time into the #posts div. But I can't seem to figure out how to scroll down once the new posts are loaded [so they are all visible]

```
// infinite scrolling on homepage
$('.load-more').click(function(e) {

    var $this = $(this);

    var offset = $this.data('offset') + 3;

    var myProperties = {
        snippet: 'infiniteScroll',
        limit: 3,
        offset: offset,
        parents: 22,
        depth: 999,
        sortby: 'publishedon',
        showHidden: 1,
        debug: 1,
        tpl: 'infiniteHomePageTpl'
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.processor",
        data: myProperties,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            var newposts = response.posts;
            $(newposts).hide().appendTo('#posts').fadeIn(800);;

            if(response.lastpost){
                console.log('nodata');
                $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }

            // scroll to last posts (not working)
            $('#posts').animate({scrollTop: $('#posts').get(0).scrollHeight}, 300);

            // Update the offset
            $this.data('offset', offset);
        },

        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },

    }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }); // ajax

}); // load more
```

I'm not sure I am understanding the scrollTop function correctly, do I need to apply it to the items I am adding or the container I'm adding them to?

[Added Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ocyxme0/3/)

Comment: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yr5x1oew/)

Comment: OK - I got it somewhat working, but it only works inside a div.. check the fiddle I added, the msg is what the json call returns - trimmed down a bit.  I basically need the whole page to scroll as items are added.

Comment: Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ocyxme0/4/)

Comment: yup - that's got it.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
 var post= $('#posts');
  var height = post[0].scrollHeight;
  post.scrollTop(height);
```

Add this code in Css

```
 #posts{
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: I won't know the height of the returned divs.

Comment: Don't wry about it. you dont need to get it.